# What's the retry configuration for a ServiceEntry using https?

Tags: istio

I'm trying to setup a Service Entry to add an external API to our mesh and take advantage of some network resilience features. First, I'd like to add retries to these API calls. I've got an example setup and working using http, but I can't figure out the configuration for https.

For example, I got this working...

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
    name: httpbin-srv-entry
spec:
    hosts:
        - httpbin.org
    ports:
        - number: 80
          name: http
          protocol: HTTP
    location: MESH_EXTERNAL
    resolution: DNS

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
    name: httpbin-vrt-srv
spec:
    hosts:
        - httpbin.org
    http:
        - route:
              - destination:
                    host: httpbin.org
          retries:
              attempts: 10
              retryOn: "5xx"
```

After making a call inside the mesh to `curl -v http://httpbin.org/status/503`, I see all of the attempts in the `istio-proxy` log:

```
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:39.327431Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:39.381075Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:39.467414Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:39.647938Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:39.681137Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:39.713335Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:39.831212Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:40.006095Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:40.189391Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
tools istio-proxy 2022-05-06T20:52:40.287682Z   debug   envoy router    [C940][S13424897362262611751] performing retry
```

The problem I'm having is setting up this example with https...

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
    name: httpbin-srv-entry
spec:
    hosts:
        - httpbin.org
    ports:
        - number: 443
          name: https
          protocol: HTTPS
    location: MESH_EXTERNAL
    resolution: DNS

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
    name: httpbin-vrt-srv
spec:
    hosts:
        - httpbin.org
    http:
        - route:
              - destination:
                    host: httpbin.org
          retries:
              attempts: 10
              retryOn: "5xx"
```

The API calls are working, but the retires aren't happening. I can tell by how quick the `curl` command ends and there's nothing in the `istio-proxy` log indicating any retries happened. I also tested by spinning up `kennethreitz/httpbin` on a different cluster and watching the access log, just thought this example was easier to demo.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51740657/510218

Full example:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
    name: httpbin-srv-entry
spec:
    hosts:
        - httpbin.org
    ports:
        - number: 80
          name: http
          protocol: HTTP
        - number: 443
          name: https
          protocol: HTTPS
    location: MESH_EXTERNAL
    resolution: DNS

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
    name: httpbin-vrt-srv
spec:
    hosts:
        - httpbin.org
    http:
        - match:
              - port: 80
          route:
              - destination:
                    host: httpbin.org
                    port:
                        number: 443
          timeout: 300s
          retries:
              attempts: 10
              retryOn: 5xx
              perTryTimeout: 3s

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
    name: originate-tls-for-httpbin
spec:
    host: httpbin.org
    trafficPolicy:
        loadBalancer:
            simple: ROUND_ROBIN
        portLevelSettings:
            - port:
                  number: 443
              tls:
                  mode: SIMPLE # initiates HTTPS when accessing httpbin.org
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).